# Comparison in negative forms

Tags: comparisons

I know about comparison in positive forms:

1. I like movies as much as you do.
2. I like movies not so much as I do TV shows.

But is it possible to do the above in negative forms?

3. I don't like movies as much as you don't like them.
4. I don't like movies not so much as I don't like TV shows.

Comment: There are excessive negatives in 3 and 4. English usually avoids excessive negatives because they become incomprehensible, e.g. *“It would not be wrong to fail to not deny that it were not false that I don't like movies as much as you don't like them.”*

Comment: Shortly, no, it isn't.

Might you get more support somewhere like SE English Language Learners?

Answer (score 3):

(1) is fine, but (2) needs to be in this form:

*I don't like movies as much as I do TV shows.*

or *I like movies, but not as much as I do TV shows.*

You can say *I don't like movies as much as you [do]*,

but if you want to make both parties' opinions negative, you have to use *dislike* *(or a synonym of it).

(3) *I dislike movies as much as you do.*

(4) *I dislike movies, but not as much as I do TV shows.*